# jquery parent sibling selector two steps back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the class of an element but can't seem to get it right here is my html

```
<div class = "grand">
  <section class = 'minimized'>
     <div class = "div-1"> <button class = 'assign-show'></button> </div>
  </section>
  <section class = 'assignment'>
     <div class = "div-2"> <button class = 'assign-hide'></button> </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

what I need is if assign-show is clicked, then add  `<section class = 'assignment'>` and `<section class = 'minimized'>`

below is my jquery script

```
$('.assign-show').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('.minimized').addClass('hide'); 
    $(this).closest('.minimized').addClass('assignment-hide');
    $(this).parent('section').siblings('.assignment').removeClass('hide');
   $(this).parent('section').siblings('.assignment').removeClass('assignment-hide'); 
 });
```

the above code works well for addclass but remove class is not working.

Comment: use next instead of siblings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is because `parent()` only travels one level up the DOM tree, yet `section` is two levels away from `.assign-show`. To fix this issue you can use either `parents()` (note, plural), or `closest()`. The latter would seem a better fit as it stops at the first matching occurrence.

Also note that you can join the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` calls together. Try this:

```
$('.assign-show').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.minimized').addClass('hide assignment-hide');
  $(this).closest('section').siblings('.assignment').removeClass('hide ssignment-hide'); 
});
```